# Playback from start instead of from current frame?

Tags: animation, smoke-simulation

I'm doing a smoke simulation right now, and I would love playback to start from my inpoint everytime I hit alt+a instead of running from the current frame.

Is that possible? 
Looking at [bpy.ops.screen.animation_play](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78_0/bpy.ops.screen.html?highlight=bpy.ops.screen.animation_play#bpy.ops.screen.animation_play) it doesn't seem so....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> (while mouse in the 3d view) and then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> again to start from frame one. If this doesn't work you should open once your timeline and move once your mouse at frame one.

Comment: good enough.... I used alt+a to stop the animation too, but esc is returning to where you initially started. Thanks!

Comment: `Esc` doesn't always return playback to frame 1 rather than to one where you started playing animation the last time. Use `Shift`+`LeftArrow` to return to frame 1.